# Remove edges that are NA from network graph in R

Tags: r, na, social-networking, network-analysis

I am new to network graphing and analysis, so apologies in advance if I am missing something obvious.

I have a network that is weighted and directed from people scoring one another on a survey. However, not everyone filled out the survey, so there are some NAs in the matrix.

Sample Data:

```
names<-c("Bob", "Amy", "Steve", "Rachel", "Leah", "Dan")
scores<-c(NA, 1,1,1,1,1,5,3,1,2,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,4,NA,NA,5,NA,5,5,1,3,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
sample_nw<-matrix(scores, nrow=6, ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(sample_nw)<-names
rownames(sample_nw)<-names
```

When I use the code below, the graph contains edges between vertices that are actually NA. I want to remove these edges so that the graph is a bit cleaner and more accurate.

```
nw_graph<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(sample_nw,
                                    weighted=TRUE, mode="directed", diag=FALSE)

plot(nw_graph, vertex.color="turquoise", vertex.size=25, edge.label=(E(nw_graph)$weight), edge.width=(E(nw_graph)$weight),edge.curved=rep(0.5))
```

This has also been an issue for when I am trying to measure degrees, as it shows that everyone is connected to everyone else, which is not true.

```
igraph::degree(nw_graph)
igraph::degree(nw_graph, mode=c("in"))
igraph::degree(nw_graph, mode=c("out"))
```

How can I handle these NAs for the network, and remove them from my plot?

Thank you!

Comment: Try replacing NA values with 0 with something like `sample_nw[is.na(sample_nw)] <- 0` and see if that helps?

Comment: @jpsmith That worked! If you happen to understand the logic behind why R gets rid of 0s and not NAs for networks, I'd love an explanation. But thank you for the simple fix!

Comment: I wish I knew what R was thinking, but alas I have no idea :)